# How can I get Broadcom 4301 to work in Crunchbang Linux?

Tags: wifi, crunchbang, broadcom

I've sunk about 6 hours into this and have not made much progress.

I've installed Crunchbang, 32-bit, Waldorf on a Dell Inspiron D600.

Before I took any steps, the network manager told me "firmware missing".
Then I ran:

> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43legacy-installer

Now, the network manager can see my network but, after I enter the network key, it won't connect.  And yes, I'm sure the key is correct.

The instructions I've been following can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)

If you need further info, please ask in the comments.

Comment: We'd need the exact steps you followed (where did you get the firmware from, ...). The page you cite seems to be quite old, many things could have changed. My cursory search says that it should be supported by some reverse engineered driver, please share your research. Look at http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/devices

Comment: The page I cited was updated last month, and the Dell is 8 years old so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Can you share the content of the kernel logs?

Answer (score 1):

Like the previous post, it would really help to know more information. There's a couple things I know I can point out:

The link is for Arch Linux, which is quite different from Crunchbang (#!). While #! is relatively small in community, many fixes found for Debian and also Ubuntu will work for #!.

Waldorf (11) is still in testing, you might have better luck with Statler (10), which you can download from http://crunchbang.org/download/statler.

You said you are running a live session. I assume there's a reason for not installing it to your hard drive. While in a live session, installing/saving does not carry over to another session. Instead, when rebooting the usb drive (starting a new live session), it will look exactly like when you first started it up.

This looks very helpful and quite straightforward: http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

If you're still having trouble, please give us more information on what you have tried so we can help you better.

Comment: I tried Waldorf because it has a non-PAE option.  If Statler has that, which I don't see, then I'll try that.  I figured I'd be better off with a stable version though.  The reason I haven't installed is this: if I can't get wifi to work, there's no point in installing.

Comment: "I have a Dell d800 that does not support pae.  I am running the latest version of Statler and it is doing great." (http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=18561) This forum has a lot of useful information on your topic. I'd recommend trying Statler and if that doesn't work for some reason, take a look at Debian.

Comment: Ah, I thought Waldorf was the stable and Statler was the unstable.  I will try it.